Gemini API not giving output when the input is a question and longer then 5 words and if it's not a question and longer then 7
I am attempting to make a website to talk to Cyrus the Great. I have set up Gemini to respond to any input as if it's Cyrus the Great but when testing it I have encountered a unusual problem. I can get a response if the input is pretty short but the input "Hi there ruler of the great Persian empire Cyrus" gets a response but "What did your people eat" doesn't. I haven't found anything for this so I'm very confused. Here's the code segment for Gemini.
import { GoogleGenerativeAI } from "@google/generative-ai";

// Fetch your API_KEY
const API_KEY = 'API_KEY';

// Access your API key
const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI(API_KEY);

window.talkToGemini = async function(){
  //Set the variable to the output from gemini
  let userInput = document.getElementById('user_input').value + " respond as if you're Cyrus the Great";

  // For text-only input, use the gemini-pro model
  const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({ model: "gemini-pro"});

  const chat = model.startChat({
    history: [
      {
        role: "user",
        parts: [{ text: userInput }],
      },
      {
       role: "model",
       parts: [{ text: "Great to meet you. What would you like to know?" }],
     },
    ],
    generationConfig: {
      maxOutputTokens: 100,
    },
  });

  var result = await chat.sendMessage(userInput);
  var response = await result.response;
  var text = response.text();
  console.log(text);

I have looked around for anyone else who is having this problem but it doesn't seem to have happened before.

If that's your actual API Key, you may want to [edit] it out and flag the question in need of moderator intervention, asking them to remove mention of the key from the edit history (see Guide on how to handle sensitive information in posts for more)

Show the exact prompt and response/error message.

The exact prompt is "What did your people eat". The response is the input box moving down a little bit but no text appearing. The network tool shows something came in.

Update your question with details and not via comments.

Just Increase the maxOutputTokens to 1000 or 5000.

Just a note to someone who are facing this issue of Gemini API not giving response, it is been observed that setting the 'output tokens' to something less than 2048 is making Gemini behave unexpectedly and return None instead of a response. You may want to modify and set it to 2048 or high.
Reference - https://github.com/google-gemini/generative-ai-python/issues/196
